# Intellij 2020.2 and class named "TestSuite"

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a application used as a custom test harness for a system. It includes an abstract class named "TestSuite." All was well until I upgraded to Intellij 2020.2; suddenly my classes that extend "TestSuite" are all marked as "error", with "TestSuite" being not found by intellij, both in the "import" statement and the "extends". If I delete both, and retype, Intellij as usual prompts me to decide which "TestSuite" to import, mine, or JUnit, or one or two others. I tell it to import mine, it fills in the code...then promptly marks it as "not resolved" again.

I restarted IntelliJ, I blew away my source and re-cloned it from git, nothing worked until I renamed my class to "TestSuite2", then the problem suddenly disappeared. My coworkers on IntelliJ 2020.1 don't see this issue (and I didn't see it until I upgraded). Anybody know what is going on? Is there any workaround, other than renaming my class? It seems like the latest IntelliJ treats the class name "TestSuite" specially and chokes when you use it.

Comment: I tried renaming "TestSuite2" back to "TestSuite". It works, the bug did not reappear. So now I don't know what is going on at all.

Comment: hello, in case the issue appears once again, please report it at YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue) providing the idea.log file (Help | Show Log in Finder). Thanks